# Display image profile: PHP

Tags: php

My problem is when I submit the button the content in the page disappear, then when I refresh the page the picture is displayed normally with all the content. So I don't understand why after submitted I have to refresh the page for display the picture.

```
<div class="widget">
    <h2>Hello, <?php echo $user_data['first_name'].' ' . $user_data['last_name']; ?>!</h2>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="profile">
            <?php

            if(isset($_FILES['profile']) == true)
            {

                if(empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) == true)
                {
                    echo 'Please choose a file!';
                }
                else
                {
                    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                    $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                    $file_size = $_FILES['profile']['size'];
                    $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                    $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];



                    if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == true && $file_size<(1024*1024) == true)
                    {
                        change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);


                        exit();
                    }
                    else if($file_size<(1024*1024) == false)
                    {
                        echo  "Image file size max 1 MB"; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                        echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(file_exists($user_data['profile']))
            {
                echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="', $user_data['first_name'], ' \'s Profile Image">';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<img src="./images/profile/default.gif" height="180"><br>';
                echo '<strong>Upload your picture</strong>';

            }

            ?>
             <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="profile"> <input type="submit">
            </form>

        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $user_data['username']; ?>">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="changepassword.php">Change password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="settings.php">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the function:

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn)
{
    $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn ;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile = '" . $file_path .  "' WHERE user_id = "  . (int)$user_id);
}
```

Comment: Without the exit(); the problem of the page disappear, but I have to submit again for display the picture( I mean the new picture because there's one as a default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you read $user_data before you save a new picture into db.
So you should reread data about profile from db after updating or set $user_data['profile'] manually to a new image path.

Comment: Probably you are right, but can you explain me better what I have to do please because I am not so expert in PHP. Thanks

Comment: Basically after the first submit upload the path in the database, and after the second submit display that image.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you were right. I solved the problem; I don't think is the best way but work for me: I made another function fetching the profile row from the database.